# How to access Octopus Tenant's common variable into our project variable that is being attached to that Tenant

Tags: octopus-deploy

I'm accessing Tenant name by `{Octopus.Deployment.Tenant.Name | ToLower}` 
but not able to access secondary region and other values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of multi-tenant deployments guide gives a full end-to-end example of working with tenant-specific variables: https://octopus.com/docs/guides/multi-tenant-deployments/multi-tena..

Comment: That link is now dead.

Comment: Or is it just truncated (?).